# Powershell to loop subfolders by Sequence

Tags: loops, powershell

I would like to use power shell to loop all subfolders and run all the files in it. But, if my root contain 3 subfolders, I would like to loop and list it accordingly to the sequence where : Subfolder C , Subfolder B and Subfoder A so that the file execution will run according to the sequence ( C-->B-->A) .

Below is my coding, Please advise me on this. Thank you so much.

```
Get-ChildItem -path "C:\Root\subfolders\" -recurse -Filter *.sql |
foreach-object -process { $.FullName }| ForEach-Object { sqlcmd -i $ }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could **sort** the list of `.sql` files to run by the *name of their parent folder* before executing them using the [Sort-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176968.aspx) cmdlet:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Root" -Recurse -Filter *.sql | `
Sort-Object -Property DirectoryName -Descending | `
Foreach-Object -Process { sqlcmd -i $.FullName }
```

Comment: Hi @Enrico Campidoglio , If the sequence in C-->A--->B , the -desc no longer working..is there any other method for this ? thank you so much